# CreateText method produces error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a button that will delete text in gross.txt. I keep getting this error:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\isaiah\Visual BASIC Programs\VB2012\Chap10\Gross Pay Solution\Gross Pay Project\bin\Debug\gross.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Or more specifically:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.

It appears the error comes from btnDelete_Click at the bottom.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtGrossPay_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtGrossPay.KeyPress

        ' Allows the text box to accept only numbers, the period, and the Backspace key
        If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> "." AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

        Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter
        outFile = IO.File.AppendText("gross.txt")
        outFile.WriteLine(txtGrossPay.Text)
        outFile.Close()

        txtGrossPay.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

        ' Declare new inFile Varable as a streamreader object
        Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader
        Dim dblLine As Double

        ' Opens gross.txt for input
        inFile = IO.File.OpenText("gross.txt")

        ' .Exists() searches /bin folder for gross.txt, returns a boolean value
        If IO.File.Exists("gross.txt") Then
            inFile = IO.File.OpenText("gross.txt")

            'Fill the list with the values
            Do Until inFile.Peek = -1

                Double.TryParse(inFile.ReadLine, dblLine)

                lstContents.Items.Add(dblLine.ToString("C2").PadLeft(6, " "c))
            Loop
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("The file you have requested does not exist", "Gross Pay Project",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If

        inFile.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Dim outDelete As IO.StreamWriter
        outDelete = IO.File.CreateText("gross.txt")
        outDelete.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue.
You were opening the file twice in your code with the line

```
inFile = IO.File.OpenText("gross.txt")
```

I commented out the first time you did it before your .Exists call.  I also added a dispose to your Delete call.  CreateText doesn't need to assign to anything so I commented out that code and added the line you needed.  I tested and these changes fixed the issue.  In fact the first change was the fix, the second one was just to clean things up.

```
 Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    'declare new inFile Varable as a streamreader object
    Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader
    Dim dblLine As Double
    'opens gross.txt for input
    ' inFile = IO.File.OpenText("gross.txt")
    '.Exists() searches /bin folder for gross.txt, returns a boolean value
    If IO.File.Exists("gross.txt") Then
        inFile = IO.File.OpenText("gross.txt")
        'fill the list with the values
        Do Until inFile.Peek = -1
            Double.TryParse(inFile.ReadLine, dblLine)
            lstContents.Items.Add(dblLine.ToString("C2").PadLeft(6, " "c))
        Loop
         inFile.Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("The file you have requested does not exist", "Gross Pay Project",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click 
    'Dim outDelete As IO.StreamWriter
    'outDelete = IO.File.CreateText("gross.txt")
    'outDelete.Close()
    IO.File.CreateText("gross.txt").Dispose
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to call dispose ...

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
Dim outDelete As IO.StreamWriter
outDelete = IO.File.CreateText("gross.txt")
outDelete.Close()

outDelete.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Also in your Do Loop are you meaning to add a line when the

```
Double.TryParse(inFile.ReadLine, dblLine)
```

fails to parse?  It seems like you would want to skip it if the parse fails

```
  Do Until inFile.Peek = -1

       if Double.TryParse(inFile.ReadLine, dblLine)  then
          lstContents.Items.Add(dblLine.ToString("C2").PadLeft(6, " "c))
        end if

  Loop
```

but up to you.

Comment: outDelete.Dispose() Doesn't solve the problem, still getting the same error.  That is a neat trick with the If statement though

Answer (score 0):

The error means what it says. Somewhere you have the file open. Perhaps in [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29)? Are you looking at the contents of the file perhaps?

Comment: no unfortunately i dont have it open, the error happened after i created the btnDelete_Click event procedure.

Comment: Regarding *"The error means what it says"*: Not always. The error message, "...  because it is being used by another process." may be lying. This is, in fact, the case in that example - the ***same*** process has it opened.